In datadog, is there a way to filter a hostmap based on the results of another query?
I have a dashboard that has a variable for specific installs of a program (1-n selected), each uniquely named. I would like to make a hostmap, that's only for the hosts for the selected installs of the program. So if you filter the dashboard for one install, the map has one hex; n installs, n hexes.
Is there a way to do that if the hosts don't all have a tag for it?
